# Best way to access shared network drives and delete specific files

Tags: python, bash, powershell

My coworker has asked me to make a script that deletes specific files that reappear after updating a program. She has been manually going into each drive and folder to delete the junk files that are added after it updates.

I have a list of the file names that always need to be deleted. I tried using python and os.remove, but ran into some problems. I would have to access the shared network drive, enter the folders, and delete the list of files she always deletes manually.

I'm not sure if python is the right tool for the job. It would probably be Bash or PowerShell, but I am not very proficient in programming.

If anyone has a suggestion on how best to do this I would be thankful.

This is the code I have right now for an example (again, not very proficient):

```
import os

filePaths = ['D:\test\remove.txt', 'F:\test\remove.txt']
         
os.remove(filePaths)
print("% s has been removed" % filePaths)
```

It gives me an error stating:

```
TypeError: remove: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list
```

Would I have to create a variable for each path and file?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Comment: Python is just as capable of doing this as any other general purpose programming language with filesystem support.

Comment: Python is a good choice, along with the others. I assume this is Windows. If you have a mounted drive, say T, then python is quite happy to use paths based on that. Maybe `os.remove("T:/sharedbuild/somefile.txt")`. There are tools like `pathlib.Path.glob` that can help you find files.

Comment: @tdelaney I added an example of the code I am trying to do. I don't think os.remove allows lists, so I assume I would have to make a variable for each path and file. If there is another way please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the list for the deletes.

```
import os

filePaths = ['D:/test/remove.txt', 'F:/test/remove.txt']
for filePath in filePaths:
    try: 
        print(f"removing {filePath}")        
        os.remove(filePath)
    except OSError as e:
        print(f"Failed, {e}")
```

Beware of backslashes, `"\t"` is the tab character. These would all work

```
"D:\\test\\remove.txt"
r"D:\test\remove.txt"
"D:/test/remove.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell:

```
$FilePaths =
@(
    'D:\test\remove.txt'
    'F:\test\remove.txt'
)

$FilesPaths | Remove-Item
```